# The adverb "up" with subjects

Tags: meaning, usage

John is up, or Jane is up, what do these two expressions mean? I mean what should come to someone's mind when it's first heard? Or do they mean anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means they are awake and, usually, out of bed.

Comment: This really needs more context, as the bare phrase can have several meanings.

Answer (score 1):

This can mean:

- to be awake (e.g. Michael is up now), related to a similar meaning of *to get up*
- for it to be one's turn in a game or to use a shared resource.  (e.g. we're playing spades, John took his turn and Michael is now up.)

Comment: Also "*Jane is up* for a challenge."

Comment: That's part of the phrasal verb *to be up for*.